# How to make some Struct's fields mandatory to fill and others optional in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have some basic struct to modeling an item's unit, eg: pcs, box, dozen, etc.
But I need to make some fields mandatory to be defined by user and some are not. Here's my implementation with `default` constructor from Rust's documentation. My problem is that Rust forced all of the field to be defined in the constructor:

```
pub struct Unit {
    pub name: String,              // this is mandatory. MUST be filled
    pub multiplier: f64,           // this is mandatory. MUST be filled
    pub price_1: Option<f64>,      // this is non-mandatory with default value NONE
    pub price_2: Option<f64>,      // this is non-mandatory with default value NONE
    pub price_3: Option<f64>,      // this is non-mandatory with default value NONE
}

// here I implement the Default just for the prices. 
// If user doesn't fill the name and multiplier field, it will throws an error
// the problem is that Rust forced all of the field to be defined in the constructor
impl Default for Unit {
    fn default() -> Unit {
        Unit {
            price_1: None,
            price_2: None,
            price_3: None,
        }
    }
}


let u = Unit {
          name: String::from("DOZEN"), // user must fill the name field
          multiplier: 20.0, // also the multiplier field
          price_1: Some(25600.0), // this is optional, user doesn't have to define this
          ..Default::default()  // call the default function here to populate the rest
        }
```

Comment: You should not have a default like that it you have fields that cant be defaulted.

Comment: So a mixed mandatory and non mandatory field is not possible then ?

Comment: not it is not possible. What would be the values for the mandatory parts if you don't set them?

Comment: I think I should force the user to fill the mandatory fields. If they don't set them, just throws an error or something else. Does it considered as an anti-pattern in Rust ?

Comment: You could try to use the builder pattern (https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/creational/builder.html) to have a way to construct your Unit structs. In the builder, the `build` method just returns an `Err` if the mandatory fields have not been set yet

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can detach the default implementation into an external struct, and then make a constructor that just needs the mandatory items:

```rust
pub struct Unit {
    pub name: String,              // this is mandatory. MUST be filled
    pub multiplier: f64,           // this is mandatory. MUST be filled
    pub prices: Prices
}

pub struct Prices {
    pub price_1: Option<f64>,      // this is non-mandatory with default value NONE
    pub price_2: Option<f64>,      // this is non-mandatory with default value NONE
    pub price_3: Option<f64>,      // this is non-mandatory with default value NONE
}

impl Default for Prices {
    fn default() -> Prices {
        Prices {
            price_1: Default::default(),
            price_2: Default::default(),
            price_3: Default::default()
        }
    }
}

impl Unit {
    pub fn new(name: String, multiplier: f64) -> Self {
        Unit {name, multiplier, prices: Default::default()}
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c95393862cad834c7479fa0c058e2145)

Comment: Thank you. While I'm agree that this is clearer, user needs to initiate the prices sometimes. The example from the Rust-playground suggests that I need to put another separate function in `struct Prices` to set the price field, eg: `fn set_prices(price_1: Option<f64>)`. and call it after unit initialization. `unit1.set_prices(..)`

Comment: @DennyHiu, in reality you can have this and still use the same as in the other answer. But whatever you feel suits you better.

Answer (score 3):

You could create an associated function, `from_name_and_multiplier()`, for creating your `Unit` values with a name and multiplier:

```
impl Unit {
    pub fn from_name_and_multiplier(name: String, multiplier: f64) -> Self {
        Self {
            name,
            multiplier,
            price_1: None,
            price_2: None,
            price_3: None,
        }
    }
}
```

This function forces you to provide both `name` and `multiplier`. Then, you can use this returned `Unit` value to initialize the `name` and `multiplier` fields of another `Unit`:

```
let u = Unit {
  price_1: Some(25600.0),
  ..Unit::from_name_and_multiplier("DOZEN".to_string(), 20.0)
};
```

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1a871a9634d39bf83168c5d51b39b236